# If-then-else vs ternary operator when returning full or empty std::optional

Tags: c++, return, c++17, option-type, return-type-deduction

(I've not found much by searching for *return statement*, *return deduce*, and similar, with tags [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[optional](/questions/tagged/optional).)

Why does this work

```cpp
#include <optional>

auto const f = [](bool b) {
    return b ? std::optional<int>(3) : std::nullopt;
};
```

while this doesn't?

```cpp
#include <optional>

auto const f = [](bool b) {
    if (b) {
        return std::optional<int>(3);
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
};
```

Why can't the compiler deduce the type from the first `return` and see it's compatiple with the second `return`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda return type deduction require the type of all return expressions match basically exactly.

`?` does a relatively complex system to find a common type of the two cases.  There is only one return statement, so so long as `?` can figure it out, lambda return type deduction doesn't care.

Just different rules.

```
auto const f = [](bool b)->std::optional<int> {
  if (b) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
};
```

this is probably the cleanest.